# Eclipse start, stop all running process

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-mars

I have Eclipse Mars.1

When i start my Eclipse, it always start with some running process

[image]

So when i Terminate that via Red button then start my work.

So why this button are always enable when i start my Eclipse.

I already google and apply some modification on my Preference setting but not helpful.

I am using Eclipse Mars.1.

Comment: what kind of Processes did you see

Comment: @RahalKanishka i did not see anything but why these all button are enabled.

Comment: I got the same problem too, do you have any Debug point sat up in any project

Comment: @RahalKanishka no.